# Standard Array,Set,Dictionary variable creation ways Swift programming language

Tags: swift

I'm a beginner in Swift language. There are many ways to declare/create variables in it. Please fill the code below. I want to know all the ways I can declare Arrays, Sets and Dictionaries.

```
var arr1 : [Int]
var arr2 = [Int]()
var arr3 : Array<Int>
var arr4 = [1,2,3,4]
var arr5 : Array = [1,2,3,4]
var arr6 : [Array<Int>]

var dict1 : [Int:Int]
var dict2 = [Int:Int]()
var dict3 : Dictionary<Int,Int>
var dict4 = [1 : 2,3 : 4]
var dict5 : Dictionary = [1 : 2,3 : 4]
var dict6 : [Dictionary<String, Int>]
var dict7 = [Dictionary<String, Int>]()
var dict8 = Dictionary<Int,Int>()

var set1 : Set<Int>
var set2 = Set<Int>()
var set3 : Set = [1,2,3]
var set4 : [Set<Int>]
var set5 = [Set<Int>]()
```

Comment: "Please fill the code below." what does that even mean?

Comment: Add a way to create a variable

Comment: ...you've got plenty, what are you looking for?

Comment: `[Dictionary<String, Int>]` is not a `Dictionary` and `[Set<Int>]` is not a `Set`. Both are arrays of their types respectively.

Comment: Note that if you think that in every section you have equivalent declarations, you are wrong (in every section)

Comment: I just want know how else can I declare variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listing contains forms to **declare** as well as **declare and initialize** a variable

Two alternative forms of the latter for Array and Dictionary

```
var arr7 : [Int] = []  // same as arr2

var dict9 : [Int:Int] = [:] // same as dict2, dict8
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these aren't even valid:

```
var arr1 : [Int] //an uninitialized var of type Int array, see note #1
var arr2 = [Int]() //an array of type Int with no elements
var arr3 : Array<Int> //same as arr1
var arr4 = [1,2,3,4] //an array of 4 Ints
var arr5 : Array = [1,2,3,4] //an array of 4 Ints with a redundant type annotation
var arr6 : [Array<Int>] //an array of arrays of Ints

var dict1 : [Int:Int] //an uninitialized var of type Dictionary (mapping Int keys to Int keys), see note #1
var dict2 = [Int:Int]() //an empty dictionary mapping Int keys to Int values
var dict3 : Dictionary<Int,Int> //same as dict1
var dict4 = [1 : 2, 3 : 4] //a dictionary with two Int : Int mappings
var dict5 : Dictionary = [1 : 2,3 : 4] //a dictionary with two Int mappings and a redundant type annotation
var dict6 : [Dictionary<String, Int>] //an uninitialized var of type array of Dictionaries from String keys to Int values.
var dict7 = [Dictionary<String, Int>]() //an empty array of dictionaries mapping String keys to Int values
var dict3 : Dictionary<Int,Int> //dict 3 repeated from above?
var dict8 = Dictionary<Int,Int>() //an empty dictionary mapping Int keys to Int values

var set1 : Set<Int> //an uninitialized var of type Set (of Int), see note #1
var set2 = Set<Int>() //an empty set of Int
var set3 : Set = [1,2,3] //a set of 3 Ints
var set4 : [Set<Int>] //an uninitialized var of type Array (of Sets of Ints), see note #1
var set5 = [Set<Int>]() //an empty array of Sets of Ints
```

## Notes

1. These variables have a type annotation, but no initialization. They can't be read from until a valid value is assigned to them

This shows a fundamental misunderstanding of `[]` notation (for Arrays, Dictionaries and Sets) and type annotations. I strongly suggest you read the language guide.

Comment: Note that a variable with only a type annotation e.g `var arr1 : [Int]` will compile on its own – it's just you cannot use it until you initialise it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the code compiled well with 1 dict3s

Comment: @KarenMartikyan Fixed my answer